# The CSS of Documentation's requested topics is off

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, design

I realized the CSS of the Requested Topics in the Documentation part had some displaying issues (very slight, but still):

[image]

The `.topic-comment` element should display 3 lines and it shows a bit of the fourth one. And the `...` in the `:after` element is a bit too low. The correct CSS should look as follow :

```
.container.dashboard .panels .topic-comment,
.container.dashboard .panel-full .topic-comment,
.container.dashboard .panels .issue-summary,
.container.dashboard .panel-full .issue-summary {
  color: #6a737c;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 12px;
  max-height: 4.5em; // Add this rule
}
.topic-comment:after {
  content: "...";
  background-color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 3em; // Instead of 38px
  box-shadow: -5px 0 5px 0 #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pushing a fix for this. Should be live in the next production build. Thanks.